# How to add text to a shape, such that when you click it or hover over it - it displays some specified text?

Tags: google-slides

Is there a function that allows users to add text to a shape, such that when you click it or hover over it - it displays some specified text?

[image]

This mouseover text effect via hyperlink works on Microsoft PowerPoint through the presenter mode.

I was wondering if there is a similar function on Slides. I have tried using the link function but it only allows me to link a URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is called alt text. From the [official reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6199477?hl=en)

> Add or edit alt text
>
> 1. Select an image, drawing, or graphic.
> 2. Right click and then Alt text.
> 3. Enter a title and description.
> 4. Click Ok.

*Using it, even in Stack Exchange is a good thing. :) It greatly helps people using screen readers.*